# how can i deploy WAR files on Tomcat using Oracle and ActiveMQ in Docker?

Tags: docker, spring-mvc, docker-compose, containers

I want to deploy all my application `war` files on `tomcat` container running in `docker` which is dependent on `Oracle 12c` Container and `ActiveMQ` container. What will be good approach?using `docker-compose` or executing 3 different images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that can done by running individual docker containers can be done using docker-compose. In fact docker-compose is built for defining and running multi-container Docker applications.